# Act on characters as if they were an image in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am learning Javascript and there is one thing I want to try:

I have a web page with an element like

`<div class="movingWord">Screwdriver</div>`

and when my mouse hovers over one of the letters of the word, I can apply a function as if it were an image (for instance, mirror it upside down, or anything else).

Can I do that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! What have you tried so far to solve this? Where did you fail? You'll get better answers (and learn more) if you attempt at doing it yourself first

Comment: Try putting every letter inside its own <div> and then apply the effects with CSS.

Answer (score 2):

On page load split your content by letter and wrap it in `<span>`, then either CSS `:hover` or JS animation applied on each element

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  let newContent = [];
  let oldContent = $('.movingWord').text().split('');

  oldContent.forEach(function (letter) {
    newContent.push($('<span>', {text: letter}));
  });
  
  $('.movingWord').html(newContent);
});
```

```css
.movingWord span {
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: black;
}

.movingWord span:hover {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="movingWord">Screwdriver</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way and the most 'permissive' way to do so is to put each letter or group of letter you want inside a span element for example.

```html
<div class="movingWord">
                        <span>S</span>
                        <span>c</span>
                        <span>r</span>
                        <span>e</span>
                        <span>w</span>
                        <span>d</span>
                        <span>r</span>
                        <span>i</span>
                        <span>v</span>
                        <span>e</span>
                        <span>r</span>
</div>
```

This way you can have an absolute control over your animation for each letter, add a class like `hover-letter` in your css and do whatever you want with each letter

Answer (score -1):

The way I understad it, you want to transform your text on hover.

```
.mirror {
   width: 200px;
   background-color: lightgray;
}

.mirror:hover {
   transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

```
<div class="">
  <h1 class="mirror">Hello World</h1>
</div>
```

These snippets for example will mirror you h1 element horizontally when the mouse touches it.

Comment: From question: _when my mouse hovers over **one of the letters** of the word_